# DTD Element: Alternative between text and element

Tags: xml, element, dtd, pcdata

I want to define a dtd for my xml document.

In this dtd, I have an element called

```
p
```

. p can contain either #PCDATA or another element (img). How can i declare this? I tried this:

```
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA | img)>
<!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
```

But that doesn't work. Response error: Error: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '*'.
When I try this:

```
<!ELEMENT p ((#PCDATA) | img)>
<!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
```

the error occurred: Error: Name cannot begin with the '#' character, hexadecimal value 0x23.

How can I achieve that p contains text or another element img? It's necessary that both options are working. One of the two options must be implemented.

```
<p>some text</p>
```

and

```
<p><img src='...' /></p>
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixed content models must have occurrence constraint of zero or more.

```
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA | img)*>
```